# Update based on previous month data in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with column Employee Name & Proposed Flag with value Powerlist or NonPowerlist also i have a month end & current Flag column. My Current Flag is having null values.

Now i need to update the current flag with the Proposed flag available on the same table but from the previous month end  data i.e while updating current flag of December i need to check the proposed flag of that employee on November.

Comment: Please post some example data and desired results not only escription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
set Current_Flag =  (Select Proposed_Flag 
                     from table 
                     where employeename = "employeename"
                     and MonthEnd = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'ddMONyyyy'))
Where employeename = "employeename"
   and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE table.monthend) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE    SYSDATE)
   and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) = 2016
```

That isn't exact, and I haven't tested the above code, but I think what you're wanting is close to that.

Comment: `"employeename"` is a column name, not a string

Comment: I know, I was trying to be generic.

Comment: This will update December 2015 and December 2014 and any December.

Comment: Also, what is the `, 'ddMONyyyy')` section for?

Comment: Thanks @MT0, changed slightly to allow for that issue.